# SQL query taking longer time to execute

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to execute the query. It take 32 min to execute. I have tried NOLOCK but only optimized it with 3 min.
the query is given below:-

```
SELECT PO.payday, PO.facility, PO.department, PO.workcenter, PO.shift, PO.team, PO.orderno, PO.fg_productno,               
       PO.sfg_productno, NoCarton = '1', NoPack = 5, NoCigarette = PO.nocigarette, VNC.sampleid, VNC.comment,               
       VNC.createdby, SampleDateTime = dbo.AF_GetUTCToLocal(VNC.UTCStartDate),               
       SampleTime = Cast(CONVERT(CHAR(10), VNC.utcstartdate, 101) AS DATETIME), VNC.ncgroup,  VNC.productcomponent,              
       VNC.nc, VNC.ncname, VNC.weightingfactor, VNC.ConsumerSensitive, VNC.[lowunits], VNC.[low %], VNC.[highunits],               
       VNC.[high %], VNC.vqi, VNC.deepcontrol,
       --Modification done for CHE10045964
       PO.ResourceClassName    
FROM   
(SELECT PayDay = WCS.payday, Facility = R.facility, Department = R.department, WorkCenter = R.workcenter,               
        Shift = WCS.workperiod, Team = SD.teamid, OrderNo = WO.orderno,               
        FG_ProductNo = P.productno + Isnull('.' + P.productrevision, ''),               
        SFG_ProductNo = CASE               
                        WHEN UCHSC.attribute_ != P.productno 
                        THEN UCHSC.attribute_               
                         ELSE NULL               
                         END,               
        WO.actualstartdate, WO.actualcompletiondate,
        NoCigarette = dbo.Af_getunitcharacteristicattribute(OD.unitid,'ZPPPI_ITEM_PACK') ,
        RC.Name as ResourceClassName              
        FROM   order_header OH               
               INNER JOIN dbo.wip_order WO ON OH.orderno = WO.orderno               
               INNER JOIN dbo.order_detail OD ON OD.orderno = WO.orderno               
               INNER JOIN dbo. product P ON WO.productid = P.id               
               INNER JOIN dbo.resource_ R ON R.resourcename = WO.resourcename AND R.resourcetype = WO.resourcetype 
               Inner Join dbo.Resource_Class RC ON R.ResourceClassID = RC.ID             
               INNER JOIN dbo.work_center_work_schedule WCS ON WO.oawipentityid = WCS.id             
               INNER JOIN at_work_center_work_schedule_detail SD ON WCS.id = SD.workcenterworkscheduleid               
               LEFT JOIN dbo.unit_characteristic UCHSC ON UCHSC.unitid = OD.unitid               
                                                       AND UCHSC.characteristic = 'ZPPPI_SPA_CIGARETTE'               
        WHERE  OH.ordertype = 23              
        GROUP  BY WCS.payday, R.facility, R.department, R.workcenter, WCS.workperiod, SD.teamid,               
                  WO.orderno, P.productno + Isnull('.' + P.productrevision, ''),               
                  CASE               
                    WHEN UCHSC.attribute_ != P.productno THEN UCHSC.attribute_               
                    ELSE NULL               
                  END,               
                  WO.actualstartdate, WO.actualcompletiondate,               
                  dbo.Af_getunitcharacteristicattribute(OD.unitid,'ZPPPI_ITEM_PACK'),
                  RC.Name
) PO INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT NC.orderno, NC.sampleid, NC.comment, NC.deepcontrol, NC.createdby, NC.utcstartdate, NC.ncgroup, NC.productcomponent,               
       NC.nc, NC.ncname, NC.weightingfactor, NC.ConsumerSensitive, NC.[lowunits], NC.[low %], NC.[highunits], NC.[high %],               
       VQI = Round(NC.weightingfactor * ( Log (1 + [low %] / 3.0 + [high %]) ), 0), 
       --Added By Sukanya Biswas(CHE10045964)
       NC.WorkCenter             
FROM  (SELECT orderno, b.sampleid, b.comment, b.deepcontrol, b.utcstartdate, b.ncgroup, b.productcomponent,               
              b.nc, b.ncname, b.weightingfactor, b.ConsumerSensitive, b.createdby,               
              [LowUnits] = Isnull(b.[1], 0),               
              [Low %] = CASE CONVERT(NVARCHAR(1),b.deepcontrol) + b.ncgroup               
                            WHEN '0Bundle'   THEN   CASE WHEN (Isnull(b.[1], 0) * 100) > 100 THEN 100 ELSE Isnull(b.[1], 0) * 100 END               
                            WHEN '1Bundle'   THEN   CASE WHEN (Isnull(b.[1], 0) * 100) > 100 THEN 100 ELSE Isnull(b.[1], 0) * 100 END                
                            WHEN '0Pack'      THEN   CASE WHEN (Isnull(b.[1], 0) * NoofCigarette ) > 100 THEN 100 ELSE Isnull(b.[1], 0) * NoofCigarette  END                
                            WHEN '1Pack'      THEN   CASE WHEN (Isnull(b.[1], 0) * NoofCigarette ) > 100 THEN 100 ELSE Isnull(b.[1], 0) * NoofCigarette  END               
                            WHEN '0Cigarette' THEN   CASE WHEN (Isnull(b.[1], 0) * 5  ) > 100 THEN 100 ELSE Isnull(b.[1], 0) * 5   END               
                            WHEN '1Cigarette' THEN   CASE WHEN (Isnull(b.[1], 0) * 1  ) > 100 THEN 100 ELSE Isnull(b.[1], 0) * 1   END               
                            WHEN '0Filter'   THEN   CASE WHEN (Isnull(b.[1], 0) * 10 ) > 100 THEN 100 ELSE Isnull(b.[1], 0) * 10  END               
                            WHEN '1Filter'   THEN   CASE WHEN (Isnull(b.[1], 0) * 10 ) > 100 THEN 100 ELSE Isnull(b.[1], 0) * 10  END               
                        ELSE Isnull(b.[1], 0)               
                        END, [HighUnits] = Isnull(b.[2], 0),        
             [High %] = CASE CONVERT(NVARCHAR(1),b.deepcontrol) + b.ncgroup               
                            WHEN '0Bundle'   THEN   CASE WHEN (Isnull(b.[2], 0) * 100) > 100 THEN 100 ELSE Isnull(b.[2], 0) * 100 END                
                            WHEN '1Bundle'   THEN   CASE WHEN (Isnull(b.[2], 0) * 100) > 100 THEN 100 ELSE Isnull(b.[2], 0) * 100 END                
                            WHEN '0Pack'      THEN   CASE WHEN (Isnull(b.[2], 0) * NoofCigarette ) > 100 THEN 100 ELSE Isnull(b.[2], 0) * NoofCigarette  END                
                            WHEN '1Pack'      THEN   CASE WHEN (Isnull(b.[2], 0) * NoofCigarette ) > 100 THEN 100 ELSE Isnull(b.[2], 0) * NoofCigarette  END                         
                            WHEN '0Cigarette' THEN   CASE WHEN (Isnull(b.[2], 0) * 5  ) > 100 THEN 100 ELSE Isnull(b.[2], 0) * 5   END               
                            WHEN '1Cigarette' THEN   CASE WHEN (Isnull(b.[2], 0) * 1  ) > 100 THEN 100 ELSE Isnull(b.[2], 0) * 1   END               
                            WHEN '0Filter'   THEN   CASE WHEN (Isnull(b.[2], 0) * 10 ) > 100 THEN 100 ELSE Isnull(b.[2], 0) * 10  END                
                            WHEN '1Filter'   THEN   CASE WHEN (Isnull(b.[2], 0) * 10 ) > 100 THEN 100 ELSE Isnull(b.[2], 0) * 10  END               
                            ELSE Isnull(b.[2], 0)               
                         END , 
                         --Added By Sukanya Biswas(CHE10045964)
                         B.WorkCenter             
            FROM (SELECT D .orderno, SampleID = DTS.id, 
            --Added By Sukanya Biswas(CHE10045964)
            DL.WorkCenter,             
                         Comment = CASE Isnull(DTS.comment_, '')               
                         WHEN '' THEN 'N/A'               
                         ELSE DTS.comment_               
                         END, UTCStartDate = DTS.actualstartdate, NC.ncgroup, NC.productcomponent, NC.nc, NC.ncname,               
                                          NC.weightingfactor, NC.ConsumerSensitive,              
                                          Severity = Isnull(QD.qualitydefectseverityid, 0),               
                                          QD.noofdefects, DTS.createdby, DeepControl = DTS.overridesumresults,                            
                                          NoofCigarette = dbo.Af_getunitcharacteristicattribute(OD.unitid,'ZPPPI_ITEM_PACK')                             
                  FROM   dbo.disposition D               
                  INNER JOIN dbo.disposition_line DL ON D .disposition = DL.disposition 
                  --Inner Join dbo.Work_Center WC ON DL.Workcenter = WC.Workcenter              
                  INNER JOIN dbo.disposition_test DT ON DT.disposition = D .disposition               
                                                     AND DT.linesequenceno =  DL.linesequenceno               
                  INNER JOIN dbo.disposition_test_sample DTS ON DTS.dispositiontestid = DT.id               
                  LEFT JOIN quality_defect QD ON QD.dispositiontestsampleid = DTS.id               
                  INNER JOIN dbo.AV_RPT_VSI_Nonconformity NC ON Isnull(QD.defectreasoncode, '00.00.00') = NC.nc              
                  LEFT JOIN ORDER_DETAIL OD ON OD.ORDERNO=D.ORDERNO            
                  WHERE  DL.linecode = 'VQ' 

                  ) A               
                  PIVOT (Sum(a.noofdefects) 
                  FOR severity IN ([1],[2])) 
          B) 
      NC
```

Comment: thank you dawood for editing.

Comment: Any explain output to share?

Comment: You can paste a plan using this site: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: in output 317 rows were affected and there are 31 attributes in the output. Also its a query from view

Comment: the plan is given here

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1Dpcn9a4

Comment: Sometimes you have to ask yourself: Am I doing too much in just one query?

Comment: Do you need to put the Join predicates inside functions? 

See if you can re-write it to remove the join on removeAf_getunitcharacteristicattribute

and also this: 
INNER JOIN dbo.AV_RPT_VSI_Nonconformity NC ON Isnull(QD.defectreasoncode, '00.00.00') = NC.nc              

For a clear example, please see my blog here: 
https://stingraedatabase.blogspot.com/2017/02/sargable-queries-in-sql-server-with.html

Answer (score 0):

As per your query filter and columns needed, please make index on respected columns.
By default SQL will create clustered index on your primary key, but you may create some other unclustered index on your table to make your execution faster.

You may find this link for your reference or Google it there are hundreds of article available on Internet for same.
"https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017"